# Using flashing notification led in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to use flashing notification led in my Android application.
When I use

```
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
```

notification is showing but there is no flashing led, just sound and vibration.

When I use

```
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
```

notification not showing at all. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind that not all devices have an LED to flash, or will use the LED for other stuff at higher priority (e.g., charging status).

Comment: @CommonsWare : But can you explain why when the OP explicitly applies each of the individual defaults as in the second code block, the `Notification` isn't shown at all?

Comment: @Squonk: No, which is why I didn't comment on that.

Comment: @CommonsWare : OK, fair enough - just curious as I've had occasional issues with Notifications which I never quite figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS
```